# In Java, should I use ArrayList<Long> or long[] ?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

I am writing a program which accepts 400 numbers of type `long` and will modify some of them depending on conditions at runtime and I want to know whether to use `ArrayList<Long>` or `long[]`.

Which will be faster to use? I am thinking of using `long[]` because size is fixed.

Comment: *Speed is not your problem*. Use an ArrayList: why? Because it'll grow automagically and is a better-behaved Collection! (I say that speed/performance is not the problem; if it *is* then you'd have some performance benchmarks to prove me wrong! Until then, don't worry about it.)

Comment: use `long[]` if size is fixed

Comment: you can use long[] if there is some data and if you have lots of data in thousands then switch to arralist for better performance and security.

Comment: @ManishNagar *"switch to arralist for better performance and security"*  Security?  How does using an `ArrayList` provide better security?

Comment: @ManishNagar and how does it perform better for lots of data over long[]?

Comment: Very helpful question, this should never have been downvoted imo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the size is fixed, `long[]` is faster, but it allows a less maintainable API, because it does not implement the `List` interface.

Note a `long[]` is faster for 2 reasons:

1. Uses primitive `long`s and not box object `Long`s (also enables better cache performace, since the `long`s are allocated contigously and the `Long`s aren't guaranteed to)
2. An array is much simpler and more efficient DS.

Nevertheless, for simpler maintainability - I would have used a `List<Long>`, unless performace is very critical at this part of the program.

If you use this collection very often in a tight loop - and your profiler says it is indeed a bottleneck - I would then switch to a more efficient `long[]`.

Comment: +1 If the size is fixed and you only want to operations that an array provides, I would suggest using an `long[]` is clearer/simpler and this is usually more important that performance.

Comment: I would still use `List<Long>` even if performance were important, and just make a `LongArrayList` class backed by `long[]`.

Answer (score 8):

As far as the speed goes, it almost does not matter for a list of 400 items. If you need to grow your list dynamically, `ArrayList<Long>` is better; if the size is fixed, `long[]` may be better (and a bit faster, although again, you would probably not notice the difference in most situations).

Comment: can you please share the source for the number "400"? It would be nice to learn the whys of such things. :)

Comment: @KarthickS It's in the first sentence of the question: "I am writing a program which accepts 400 numbers of type long..."

Comment: Sorry. Did not notice that part earlier. Thanks.
But, how did you determine that there is no difference for the given number?

Answer (score 5):

There are few things which haven't been mentioned in other answers:

- A generic collection is in actuality a collection of `Object`s, or better said, this is what Java compiler will make of it. This is while `long[]` will always remain what it is.
- A consequence of the first bullet point is that if you do something that eventually puts something other then `Long` into your collection, in certain situations the compiler will let it through (because Java type system is unsound, i.e. as an example, it will allow you to upcast and then re-cast to a completely disparate type).
- A more general consequence of these two is that Java generics are half-baked and in some less trivial cases such as reflection, serialization etc. may "surprise" you. It is in fact safer to use plain arrays, then generics.

---

```
package tld.example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Example {

    static void testArray(long[] longs) {
        System.out.println("testArray");
    }

    static void testGeneric(List<Long> longs) {
        System.out.println("testGeneric");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String... arguments) {
        List<Long> fakeLongs = new ArrayList<Long>();
        List<Object> mischiefManaged = (List<Object>)(Object)fakeLongs;
        mischiefManaged.add(new Object());
        // this call succeeds and prints the value.
        // we could sneak in a wrong type into this function
        // and it remained unnoticed
        testGeneric(fakeLongs);

        long[] realLongs = new long[1];
        // this will fail because it is not possible to perform this cast
        // despite the compiler thinks it is.
        Object[] forgedLongs = (Object[])(Object)realLongs;
        forgedLongs[0] = new Object();
        testArray(realLongs);
    }
}
```

This example is a bit contrived because it is difficult to come up with a short convincing example, but trust me, in less trivial cases, when you have to use reflection and unsafe casts this is quite a possibility.

Now, you have to consider that besides what is reasonable, there is a tradition. Every community has a set of it's customs and tradition. There are a lot of superficial beliefs, such as those voiced here eg. when someone claims that implementing `List` API is an unconditional goodness, and if this does not happen, then it must be bad... This is not just a dominating opinion, this is what overwhelming majority of Java programmers believe in. After all, it doesn't matter *that* much, and Java, as a language has a lot more of other shortcomings... so, if you want to secure your job interview or simply avoid conflicts with other Java programmers, then use Java generics, no matter the reason. But if you don't like it - well, perhaps just use some other language ;)

Answer (score 2):

long[] is both much faster and takes much less memory. Read "Effective Java" Item 49: "Prefer primitive types to boxed primitives"

Answer (score 2):

I think better to use ArrayList because it is much much easier to maintain in long runs. In future if the size of your array gets increased beyond 400 then maintaining a long[] has lot of overhead whereas ArrayList grows dynamically so you don't need to worry about increased size.
Also, deletion of element is handled in much better way by ArrayList than static arrays (long[]) as they automatically reorganize the elements so that they still appear as ordered elements.
Static arrays are worse at this.

Comment: I dont want to delete but just modify the element at runtime

Comment: In that case go with static arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one of the many list implementations that work on primitive types? [TLongArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TLongArrayList.html) for instance. It can be used just like Javas List but is based on a long[] array. So you have the advantages of both sides.

HPPC has a short overview of some libraries: https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc/blob/master/ALTERNATIVES.txt